# Chart.js time series format issue with options

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I work with chart.js and i try to format x axis time series something would be difficult to format time series. i need to display tick interval with 2 hours.

now i got time series from my database looks like this.

[image]

but i want to display something like this

[image]

i try with scale x axis like this

```
scales:{
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        format: "HH",
        unit: 'hour',
        unitStepSize: 2,
        displayFormats: {
          'hour': 'HH', 
        },
    }]
}
```

if i try like this nothing changes if i add options before scales i did not get any data it shows empty graph. any idea please.

```
type: 'line',
             data: {
                 xLabels: labels,
                 datasets: [
                     {
                         label: 'G.Oil', fill: true, lineTension: 0.1, backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)", borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                         borderCapStyle: 'butt', borderDash: [], borderDashOffset: 0.0, borderJoinStyle: 'miter', pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                         pointBackgroundColor: "#fff", pointBorderWidth: 1, pointHoverRadius: 5, pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)", pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                         pointHoverBorderWidth: 2, pointRadius: 1, pointHitRadius: 10, data: datay, spanGaps: false,
                     }
                 ],

             },
             options: {
                 scales: {
                     xAxes: [{

                     }]

                 }
             }
```

Comment: Your config looks pretty good to me.  Can you provide your full chart config with data so I can re-create this?

Comment: I added above code please let me know if you got time series what i want. thank you.

Comment: I am having this same issue, anytime I add `type: time`, it fails. See [chart js time](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units)